# Get JSONObject from retrofit2 response

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, pojo, okhttp

How to get in retrofit2 unknown JSON object from response object like this request (with OkHttp3):

```
Observable<Response<MyResponseObject>> apiCall(@Body body);
```

MyResponseObject look like this:

```
public class MyResponseObject {

    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;

    @SerializedName("info")
    public JSONObject info;

    @SerializedName("question_id")
    public String questionId;

   }
```

I want to get

> JSONObject info

like a regular object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `JSONObject` but you can try `Observable<Response<JsonElement>>` which has a similar API.

I believe that should deserialize your Json into a `JsonElement` object

You can also call `Response.body()` or `Response.errorBody()` if you just need the json String.

Comment: Thanks Robert! @RobertEstivill

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another class (Info):

```
public static class Info {

    @SerializedName("description")
    public String mDescription;
    @SerializedName("preview_image")
    public String mPreviewImage;

}
```

and in MyResponseObject:

```
@SerializedName("info")
public Info info;
```

Comment: But i don't know how the JSONObject look like